# PHP - Prevent quotation escape in my rss feed script

Tags: php

My script reads an RSS feed, grabs the data and spits it back out with a tooltip containing the description of the feed. It works, but I need to know how to handle unexpected punctuation like quotation marks or apostrophes. As you can see, I'm already cutting the description string off at < to prevent some html errors I encountered (that is a secondary problem).

```
$limit = 10;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $full = $feed[$x]['full'];
    $fullformat = substr($full, 0, strpos($full, "<"));
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'" class="rss tooltip" title="'.$fullformat.'">'.$title.'</a><br>';
    echo '<small><em> ( '.$date.' )</em></small></p>';


}
```

In particular its this line here that spits out the link with a tooltip class. Currently quotation marks will end my string early. I have seen some other posts on the topic, but I'm having a hardtime applying it to my dynamic string here.

```
        echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'" class="rss tooltip" title="'.$fullformat.'">'.$title.'</a><br>';
```

1>How can I make sure this string comes over intact in my current setup?

2>Is there a way to handle this string if the description has html code like a hyperlink as well?

Thank you!

Comment: [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) and/or [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: Why is the Internet asking questions...?

Comment: I'd suggest you checkout [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), it's a very good tool for stuff like this.